# How do I use a single event node to assign events to multiple children DOM elements?

Tags: google-closure, google-closure-library

In my Google Closure code, I want to assign an event to every single span in a div.

HTML:

```
  <div id="container">
    <span>foo</span>
    <span>bar</span>
    <span>bacon is delicious</span>
  </div>
```

Closure Javascript:

```
  var container = goog.dom.getElement('container');
  var spans = goog.dom.getChildren(container);
  for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    eventHandler.listen(
        spans[i],
        goog.events.EventType.CLICK,
        function (e) {
          doSomeStuff(e.target);
        }
  }
```

This loop seems inefficient though because it seems to assign an event node to every single span element. Can I somehow assign a single event node to the containing div and have the callback function run when a click event on a span bubbles up to the containing div?

In jQuery, I believe the difference between the `live()` and `delegate()` functions parallels the issue I am dealing with here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never used Google Closure, but you are already using `e.target`. By just adding one listener to the container you can obtain the actually clicked element by using `e.target`.

```
var container = goog.dom.getElement('container');

eventHandler.listen(
    container,
    goog.events.EventType.CLICK,
    function (e) {
        doSomeStuff(e.target);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, wouldn't e.target return the containing div though?

Comment: Did you test it? I'd be very surprised if Closure would change the meaning of target: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.target

Comment: e.target WILL return the containing div ONLY if you click on it, i.e. not on a child but on the space between the children.